# amslatex theorem numbering

Tags: numbering

I am writing a report that has in-text exercises as well as end-of-chapter exercises.  I want all the exercises to be numbered consecutively.  I want the in-text exercises begin with theitalized  word "Exercise", followed by the numbering.  And for the end-of-chapter ones, I do *not* have the word "Exercise" in front, just the numbering.

I tried to do this using the \theoremstyle in amstext but the numbering do not come out correctly.  Here is a minimal (non)-working example:

```
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
Cite the second exercise  \ref{two}.  Cite the third exercise \ref{three}.

\begin{exer}  \label{one}   First exercise.    \end{exer}

End of Chapter Exercises

\stepcounter{exer}  \theexer.  \label{two}   Second Exercise.

\stepcounter{exer}  \theexer.  \label{three} Third Exercise.
\end{document}
```

When I run this code, I end up with the output

```
Cite the second exercise 1.  Cite the third exercise 1.

Exercise 1.  First exercise.

End of Chapter Exercises.

2.  Second Exercise.

3.  Third Exercise.
```

which is incorrect.   If I replace latex code for the second and the third exercises with

```
\begin{exer}  \label{two} Second exercise.  \end{exer}

\begin{exer}  \label{three}  Third exercise.  \end{exer}
```

then the numbering come out correctly, but not in the format I need.

I'm really baffled.  Your help is most appreciative.  THANKS!

Comment: `\refstepcounter` is what you need. Be careful with spaces.

Comment: Brilliant!   Replacing \stepcounter with \refstepcounter solves my problem.  THANKS!    Follow up question:  Could you elaborate on what you mean by "be careful with spaces"?

Comment: It would be useful if you showed the definition of `exer`. In this particular case, spaces in the input don't really affect the output, but only because you're lucky.

Comment: oops -- I forgot to cut and paste the definition of ````exer````.  Here it is:  ````\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{exer}{Exercise}
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`, so that a proper value to be referenced is set.

On the other hand, I'd prefer a more abstract approach:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{exer}{Exercise}

\newtheoremstyle{endchapterexer}
  {0pt}        % ABOVESPACE
  {0pt}        % BELOWSPACE
  {\upshape}   % BODYFONT
  {0pt}        % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\upshape}   % HEADFONT
  {.}          % HEADPUNCT
  { }          % HEADSPACE
  {\thmnumber{#2}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\theoremstyle{endchapterexer}
\newtheorem{eexer}[exer]{}


\begin{document}

\section{First section}

Cite the second exercise  \ref{two}.  Cite the third exercise \ref{three}.

\begin{exer}\label{one}
First exercise.
\end{exer}

\subsection*{End of Chapter Exercises}

\begin{eexer}\label{two}
Second Exercise.
\end{eexer}

\begin{eexer}\label{three}
Third Exercise.
\end{eexer}

\end{document}
```

[image]